# How to create schema table datatype longtext?

Tags: php, laravel, schema, laravel-4

I need some help.
Example:

```
$table->text('description');
```

But, how to code/write, if I want my datatype is 'LONGTEXT' ?

I unable to find documentation on this @ http://laravel.com/docs/schema

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Laravel 4.2 / 5.1+

Simply use the recently added `longText` method.

```
Schema::create('posts', function ($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    // ...
    $table->longText('description');
    // ...
}
```

## Pre-Laravel 4.2 / 5.1

There is no way of doing that with the regular Laravel Schema classes, since it does not implement such type. If you really need it, you could use the Schema class to create the table, and then alter the table using a SQL query to add this field. For instance, you could have:

```
Schema::create('posts', function ($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    // ...
    $table->text('description');
    // ...
}

DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `posts` COLUMN `description` `description` LONGTEXT;');
```

Comment: There needs to be a pull request to make a `->longtext` and `->mediumtext` methods I've ran into this multiple times.

Comment: @MichaelCalkins if you think that'd be useful, open an issue with the proposal on their repository.

Comment: It should be  DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `posts` CHANGE `description` `description` LONGTEXT;');

Comment: Now DB:: statement is not necessary. because laravel has already provide 
$table->longText('description'); LONGTEXT equivalent column. Please refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations

Comment: @Yagneshbhalala thanks for pointing that out. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 11):

It's available now. From the docs

```
$table->longText('description');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
     Schema::table('table_namae', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->longText('column_name');
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to simple write datatype long text in place of string

```
Schema::table('table name ', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->longText('attachments');
});
```

I have this work for you.

for more details go through the link 
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema